# After enclosing App inside Context, screen is not rendering anything

Tags: reactjs, react-native

i am trying to build a react native blog app with context to transfer data to any child
here is my App.js

```
    import * as React from 'react';
    import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
    import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
    import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

    import IndexScreen from './src/screens/IndexScreen';
    import { BlogProvider } from './src/context/BlogContext';

    const Stack = createStackNavigator();

    const App = () => {
    return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName='Index'>
        <Stack.Screen name="Index" component={IndexScreen} options={{title: 'Blogs'}}/>
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
    );
    }

    //export default App;

    export default () => {
    return (
    <BlogProvider>
      <App/>
    </BlogProvider>
    )
    }
```

here is my BlogContext.js

```
import React from 'react'

const BlogContext = React.createContext();
//const BlogContext = NavigationContext;

export const BlogProvider = ({ childern }) => {
    return (<BlogContext.Provider>
        {childern}
    </BlogContext.Provider>
    )
}

export default BlogContext;
```

Index.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'

const IndexScreen = () => {
    return (
        <View>
            <Text> index screen</Text>
        </View>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});

export default IndexScreen;
```

it is rendering on my ios simulator blank, if i don't enclose App within BlogProvider it renders successfully. i am trying to learn react native with udemy, not sure about how context work, any help would be appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misspelled `children`, so nothing is actually getting rendered by `BlogProvider`.

Comment: No problem - mind accepting the answer please?